# Использование Wait() Pulse(). Разделение общего ресурса

Tags: c#

Пишу простенькую программу, в которой есть несколько потоков, и каждый из них поочередно получает доступ к общему ресурсу и выполняет какое-то действие. Я понимаю, что Wait() - освобождает объект блокировки, и блокирует выполнение потока пока другой поток не вызовет Pulse(), ну и Pulse() - позволяет потоку в находящемуся в Wait() выполнятся дальше.

Ресурс

```
class Sourse
{
    object objLock = new object();

    public void toDo(string name)
    {
        lock (objLock)
        {
            Monitor.Pulse(objLock);
            Console.WriteLine($"Поток {name} получил доступ и выполняется.");
            Monitor.Wait(objLock); 
        }
    }
}
```

Мои треды

```
class MyThread
{
    Thread thrd;
    static Sourse srs = new Sourse();

    public MyThread(string name)
    {
        thrd = new Thread(this.Run);
        thrd.Name = name;
        thrd.Start();
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            srs.toDo(thrd.Name);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

И точка входа в программу:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyThread first = new MyThread("1");
        MyThread second = new MyThread("2");
        MyThread third = new MyThread("3");
    }
}
```

Если я организовываю код таким образом, каким показал выше - выполняется несколько потоков одновременно, действия никак не синхронизированы. Если я пишу таким образом:

```
lock (objLock)
    {
        Monitor.Wait(objLock); 
        Console.WriteLine($"Поток {name} получил доступ и выполняется.");
        Monitor.Pulse(objLock);
    }
```

То разумеется все потоки заблокируются не выполнив никаких действий, и все встанут в ожидание. Худо бедно необходимый мне результат достигается если я организовываю ресурс следующим образом:

```
      bool key = true;
      lock (objLock)
        {
            if(key == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Поток {name} получил доступ и выполняется");
                key = false;
                Monitor.Wait(objLock);
            }
            else
            {
                key = true;
                Monitor.Pulse(objLock);
            }
        }
```

но подобная запись выглядит как костыльный костыль, и тем более, не отвечает всем выдвигаемым требованиям, так как при старте программы сразу 2 потока получает доступ и выполняется одновременно, а этого к слову того не должно быть. Вопрос в следующем: как реализовать поочередный доступ из нескольких потоков к общему ресурсу таким образом, чтобы ресурс всегда был доступен только одному потоку? Можно ли добиться нужного мне результата без подобных булевых кеев?

Answer (score 2):

У вас уже используется lock, который внутри использует Monitor. Ручной работой через Monitor вы ему мешаете. Просто уберите ручные вызовы и все заработает.

```
class Sourse
{
    object objLock = new object();

    public void toDo(string name)
    {
        lock (objLock)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Поток {name} получил доступ и выполняется.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: попробуйте на практике и посмотрите что получится

Comment: @АлексейФедотов вы не поверите, попробовал. блока lock,  связанного с одним объектом objLock в каждый момент заходит не больше одного потока. Вы какого-то другого поведения ожидали?

Comment: @АлексейФедотов хотите наглядного результата - перенесите "работу" (вызов Thread.Sleep(1000);) внутрь этого lock, чтобы ресурс блокировался на достаточно долгое время, а не только на время вывода сообщения.

Comment: каждую секунду у меня выводится по три сообщения на консоль, если я меняю свой код Sourse на ваш

Comment: @АлексейФедотов это потому что вы блокируете только на время вывода на консоль. Переставьте Thread.Sleep внутрь лока.

Comment: изначально ставилась задача написать программу с использованием Wait() Pulse(). Перенести Sleep() в лок - это идея хорошая, моя программа теперь работает так как должно

Comment: @АлексейФедотов Wait и Pulse имеют другие предназначения. Если вам нужен эксклюзивный доступ к ресурсу используйте просто lock

Comment: @Zergatul другие предназначения это какие?

Comment: @PashaPash На сколько известно, `objLock` нужно делать статиком, иначе он будет свой на каждый экземпляр, и соответственно общая блокировка не будет работать.

Comment: @АлексейФедотов для упорядоченности каких-то действий. Один поток сообщает другому, что он завершил какую-то работу, и другой поток может начинать. Например, в вас есть бесконечный цикл, который ждет прихода сообщения в коллекцию List<>. С другого потока вы добавляете что то в список и посылаете сигнал в поток с бесконечным циклом, и он начинает обрабатывать сообщение.

Comment: @ГеннадийП не нужно, если цель - синхронизация доступа к одному экземпляру, как в вопросе.